# Comparing 3 columns to develop 2 new columns

Tags: excel, vba

Use Data from columns 1 through 3 to generate new columns 4 and 5

Autofilter and if-else/while

Dataset

```
A   1   2020
A   2   2020
A   3   2020
A   1   2020
B   2   2021
B   2   2020
B   2   2021
B   2   2020
C   1   2021
C   1   2020
C   1   2020
```

Criterion   Result
If all 1  / 1
If all 2  / 2
If any 3  / 3
If 1 and 2  /   3
If all 3 /  3

Criterion   Result
If all 2020 /   2020
If all 2021 /   2021
If both / 2020_2021

Expected results are listed

Comment: Your question will likely be closed pretty quickly unless you make some fixes - please see [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Column 4

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,B1)=COUNTIF(A:A,A1),B1,3)
```

For Column 5:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,C:C,C1)=COUNTIF(A:A,A1),C1,"2020_2021")
```

[image]